# AVAudioSession mode switch volume difference

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, twilio, avaudiosession

I'm trying to combine media playback with VoIP feature (via [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios)) for iOS 9 and 8.
While an audio stream plays in the background, I connect or disconnect a Voice Conference session which results in a volume jump from value X to value Y. This jump can be heard, as well as observed by a `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance].outputVolume` value change.
I would like to prevent this jump and keep the volume at a constant level, unless the user manually decides to change it.
Further investigation showed that while AVAudioSession's category is set to **AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord**, switching between modes
`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:&error]`
and
`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error]`
causes the app to operate in two completely separate volume scales, respectively.
i.e there a volume for Mode "Default" and a completely unrelated volume for Mode "Voice Chat".
[AVAudioSession's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setMode:error:) seems to omit any mention of volume in relation to mode/category switches and I can't find anything relevant on the interwebs...

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Megan from Twilio here.

I'm not most familiar with the iOS SDK but you should be able to control connection audio from `TCDevice` parameters `incomingSoundEnabled`, `outgoingSoundEnabled`, and `disconnectSoundEnabled` as [documented here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios/TCDevice).

Otherwise, I would suggest looking at the `sharedInstance` properties of AVAudioSession that the Twilio SDK calls upon as demonstrated [in this post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/a-swift-adventure-add-audio-controls-to-basicphone.html):

`setCategory:error:`

`setActive:error:`

`overrideOutputAudioPort:error:`

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Megan, thank you but this is not what I'm looking for. incomingSoundEnabled/outgoingSoundEnabled is just the chime sound on/off property. In my situation, when Twilio connects, the volume of the whole session changes and stays like that until Twilio disconnects. I don't think this behaviour is specific to Twilio. I can reproduce this dual volume situation simply by calling 'setMode' on AVAudioSession. I was hoping to learn the reason behind it and how can I keep the volume constant while playing with 'setMode'

Answer (score 1):

When setting your play and record category, pass `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker` as an option:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&error];
```

This overrides the default play-and-record behaviour of switching from the speaker to the much quieter receiver. The reason for this being that play-and-record was designed for telephony, where you'd be holding the phone to year ear & presumably wouldn't want to have your hearing damaged by loud sounds.

Comment: this would explain the volume difference but can I somehow force it to be constant? assume I'm in PlayAndRecord from the get go and I switch from ModeDefault to ModeVoiceChat while output is always a headset